# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel / IllegalMessage

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl

I have an issue connecting to my https server, on only some windows machine (around 1% of my users, who have always have the issue).

I can reproduce the issue with a simple powershell wget "https://notasolutions.com/qlm/qlmservice.asmx"

I have the issue by scipt and code, using httpwebrequest or httpclient

The browsers on the customer machine have no issue displaying theses pages (even msedge in IE mode).
There is no client certificate expected. Oddly enough, BITS seems to work perfectly.

If I fire a debug proxy -like Fiddler- everything work fine when enabling https decrypt, so it doesn't help... I have attached below the non decrypted handshake taken by fiddler.

I have tried to enable SchUseStrongCrypto, change SystemDefaultTlsVersions, checked that SCHannel have nothing special, change every possible settings in inetcpl.cpl ...

Get-TlsCipherSuite give me a normal suit list, with multiple of them being listed on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=notasolutions.com

Here is the System.Net trace :

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering WebClient#36848977::DownloadDataAsync(https://notasolutions.com/qlm/qlmservice.asmx#254366122)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering WebRequest::Create(https://notasolutions.com/qlm/qlmservice.asmx)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering HttpWebRequest#22452836::HttpWebRequest(https://notasolutions.com/qlm/qlmservice.asmx#254366122)
System.Net Information: 0 : [21180] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [21180] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting HttpWebRequest#22452836::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#22452836
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering HttpWebRequest#22452836::BeginGetResponse()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering ServicePoint#46153895::ServicePoint(proxy.notaires.fr:8080)
System.Net Information: 0 : [21180] Associating HttpWebRequest#22452836 with ServicePoint#46153895
System.Net.Cache Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering RequestCacheProtocol#46418718::GetRetrieveStatus(HttpWebRequest#22452836)
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [21180] Request#22452836, Policy = Level:NoCacheNoStore, Cache Uri = https://notasolutions.com/qlm/qlmservice.asmx
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [21180] Request Method = GET.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [21180] Selected cache Key = https://notasolutions.com/qlm/qlmservice.asmx
System.Net.Cache Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting RequestCacheProtocol#46418718::GetRetrieveStatus()    -> result = DoNotTakeFromCache
System.Net Information: 0 : [21180] Associating Connection#50920718 with HttpWebRequest#22452836
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering HttpWebRequest#60345850::HttpWebRequest(http://proxy.notaires.fr:8080/#-739311139)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting HttpWebRequest#60345850::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering ServicePoint#19246503::ServicePoint(proxy.notaires.fr:8080)
System.Net Information: 0 : [21180] Associating HttpWebRequest#60345850 with ServicePoint#19246503
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering HttpWebRequest#60345850::BeginGetResponse()
System.Net Information: 0 : [21180] Associating Connection#58755095 with HttpWebRequest#60345850
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering Socket#59312528::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting Socket#59312528::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering Socket#1680021::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting Socket#1680021::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering DNS::TryInternalResolve(proxy.notaires.fr)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering Socket#59312528::BeginConnectEx()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Entering Socket#59312528::InternalBind(0.0.0.0:0#0)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting Socket#59312528::InternalBind() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting Socket#59312528::BeginConnectEx()   -> ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#28560362
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting HttpWebRequest#60345850::BeginGetResponse()     -> ContextAwareResult#15764116
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting HttpWebRequest#22452836::BeginGetResponse()     -> ContextAwareResult#66663381
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [21180] Exiting WebClient#36848977::DownloadDataAsync() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Entering Socket#59312528::EndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#28560362)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Entering Socket#59312528::InternalEndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#28560362)
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [20452] Socket#59312528 - Connexion créée entre 192.1.100.104:53731 et 172.30.100.100:8080.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Exiting Socket#59312528::InternalEndConnect() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Exiting Socket#59312528::EndConnect() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Entering Socket#1680021::Close()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Entering Socket#1680021::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Exiting Socket#1680021::Close() 
System.Net Information: 0 : [20452] Connection#58755095 - Connexion créée entre 192.1.100.104:53731 et 172.30.100.100:8080.
System.Net Information: 0 : [20452] Associating HttpWebRequest#60345850 with ConnectStream#12547953
System.Net Information: 0 : [20452] HttpWebRequest#60345850 - Request: CONNECT notasolutions.com:443 HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [20452] ConnectStream#12547953 - Envoi des en-têtes
{
Host: notasolutions.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Entering Socket#59312528::UnsafeBeginSend()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [20452] Exiting Socket#59312528::UnsafeBeginSend()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#11429296
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Data from Socket#59312528::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000000 : 43 4F 4E 4E 45 43 54 20-6E 6F 74 61 73 6F 6C 75 : CONNECT notasolu
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000010 : 74 69 6F 6E 73 2E 63 6F-6D 3A 34 34 33 20 48 54 : tions.com:443 HT
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000020 : 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D 0A-48 6F 73 74 3A 20 6E 6F : TP/1.1..Host: no
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000030 : 74 61 73 6F 6C 75 74 69-6F 6E 73 2E 63 6F 6D 0D : tasolutions.com.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000040 : 0A 50 72 6F 78 79 2D 43-6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F : .Proxy-Connectio
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000050 : 6E 3A 20 4B 65 65 70 2D-41 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A 0D : n: Keep-Alive...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000060 : 0A                                              : .
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering Socket#59312528::EndSend(OverlappedAsyncResult#11429296)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting Socket#59312528::EndSend()  -> Int32#97
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering Socket#59312528::UnsafeBeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting Socket#59312528::UnsafeBeginReceive()   -> OverlappedAsyncResult#12036987
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Data from Socket#59312528::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000000 : 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31-20 32 30 30 20 43 6F 6E : HTTP/1.1 200 Con
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000010 : 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 20-65 73 74 61 62 6C 69 73 : nection establis
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000020 : 68 65 64 0D 0A 0D 0A                            : hed....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering Socket#59312528::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#12036987)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting Socket#59312528::EndReceive()   -> Int32#39
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] Connection#58755095 - Ligne d'état reçue : Version=1.1, StatusCode=200, StatusDescription=Connection established.
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] Connection#58755095 - En-têtes reçus
{

}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] ConnectStream#42715336::ConnectStream(Mise en mémoire tampon de -1 octets.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] Associating HttpWebRequest#60345850 with ConnectStream#42715336
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] Associating HttpWebRequest#60345850 with HttpWebResponse#36963566
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering HttpWebRequest#60345850::EndGetResponse()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting HttpWebRequest#60345850::EndGetResponse()   -> HttpWebResponse#36963566
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering HttpWebRequest#60345850::GetResponse()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting HttpWebRequest#60345850::GetResponse()  -> HttpWebResponse#36963566
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering HttpWebResponse#36963566::GetResponseStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] ContentLength=-1
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting HttpWebResponse#36963566::GetResponseStream()   -> ConnectStream#42715336
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] TlsStream#25474675::.ctor(host=notasolutions.com, #certs=0, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Tls13)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] Associating HttpWebRequest#22452836 with ConnectStream#3038911
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] HttpWebRequest#22452836 - Request: GET /qlm/qlmservice.asmx HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] ConnectStream#3038911 - Sending headers
{
Host: notasolutions.com
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] SecureChannel#45330878::.ctor(hostname=notasolutions.com, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     Default TLS SSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] SecureChannel#45330878 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] SecureChannel#45330878::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord, UseStrongCrypto), m_ProtocolFlags=(Tls10Client, Tls11Client, Tls12Client, Tls13Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential2)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = notasolutions.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=262, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering Socket#59312528::BeginSend()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting Socket#59312528::BeginSend()    -> OverlappedAsyncResult#66629781
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Data from Socket#59312528::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000000 : 16 03 01 01 01 01 00 00-FD 03 03 5C 8D A9 5B 65 : ...........\..[e
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000010 : AF 5A 02 00 4C 7D 5A DC-07 D8 41 D2 5C 99 C2 FA : .Z..L}Z...A.\...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000020 : 66 DA 16 A8 03 2B BC 9E-2E 06 5F 20 19 11 11 16 : f....+...._ ....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000030 : DA CC 00 38 62 D1 0E 5F-6E E0 2E 9F 9F 12 AF D8 : ...8b.._n.......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000040 : BE C2 19 64 B4 05 65 22-A1 BC 39 E1 00 28 13 02 : ...d..e"..9..(..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000050 : 13 01 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30-C0 2F C0 24 C0 23 C0 28 : ...,.+.0./.$.#.(
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000060 : C0 27 C0 0A C0 09 C0 14-C0 13 00 9D 00 9C 00 3D : .'.............=
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000070 : 00 3C 00 35 00 2F 01 00-00 8C 00 00 00 16 00 14 : .<.5./..........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000080 : 00 00 11 6E 6F 74 61 73-6F 6C 75 74 69 6F 6E 73 : ...notasolutions
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000090 : 2E 63 6F 6D 00 2B 00 09-08 03 04 03 03 03 02 03 : .com.+..........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 000000A0 : 01 00 0D 00 14 00 12 04-01 05 01 02 01 04 03 05 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 000000B0 : 03 02 03 02 02 06 01 06-03 00 23 00 00 00 0A 00 : ..........#.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 000000C0 : 08 00 06 00 1D 00 17 00-18 00 33 00 26 00 24 00 : ..........3.&.$.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 000000D0 : 1D 00 20 67 10 95 EF 8A-31 CD 09 23 0E FD AD 32 : .. g....1..#...2
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 000000E0 : E9 0D 03 47 91 57 AC 83-AD E3 22 83 AA 0D E2 0A : ...G.W....".....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 000000F0 : 49 93 56 00 31 00 00 00-17 00 00 FF 01 00 01 00 : I.V.1...........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000100 : 00 2D 00 02 01 01                               : .-....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Entering Socket#59312528::EndSend(OverlappedAsyncResult#66629781)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Exiting Socket#59312528::EndSend()   -> Int32#262
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Entering Socket#59312528::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Exiting Socket#59312528::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#62476613
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Data from Socket#59312528::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] 00000000 : 15 03 03 00 02                                  : .....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Entering Socket#59312528::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#62476613)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Exiting Socket#59312528::EndReceive()    -> Int32#5
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Entering Socket#59312528::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9880] Exiting Socket#59312528::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#11404313
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Data from Socket#59312528::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] 00000000 : 02 28                                           : .(
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering Socket#59312528::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#11404313)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting Socket#59312528::EndReceive()   -> Int32#2
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = ac07220:2df3d, targetName = notasolutions.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14548] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering Socket#59312528::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [14548] Exception in HttpWebRequest#22452836:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering HttpWebRequest#22452836::EndGetResponse()
System.Net Error: 0 : [14548] Exception in HttpWebRequest#22452836::EndGetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Entering HttpWebRequest#22452836::Abort()
System.Net Error: 0 : [14548] Exception in HttpWebRequest#22452836:: - The request was aborted: The request was canceled..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14548] Exiting HttpWebRequest#22452836::Abort()
```

When configuring Fiddler without HTTPS handling, we can see the SSLV3 handshake emitted by the client :

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 4F 7C F6 68 3E CA B1 AA 59 1E 19 EF 0B 98 B1 E9 BC BA A2 C6 CD B4 4B 73 34 B0 8D 75 F7 37 C7 B8
"Time": 20/10/2025 20:15:43
SessionID: 1A C4 FE 06 DB BE 9A CA 3E C3 FE 78 4D 57 02 17 4C E3 92 AC E9 6E FD A9 FD 49 B9 A8 8A 42 1F DE
Extensions: 
    server_name notasolutions.com
    supported_versions  Tls1.3, Tls1.2, Tls1.1, Tls1.0
    signature_algs  rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
    SessionTicket   empty
    supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    key_share   00 24 00 1D 00 20 6C F0 2E 00 DD 20 61 78 D7 D6 E4 32 81 5A 04 7F 1B 3D DE 7A 16 7F F1 FC AF C6 88 76 FB 94 5F 75
    post_handshake_auth
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
    psk_key_exchange_modes  01 01
Ciphers: 
    [1302]  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [1301]  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

Same handshake when the page is successfully opened through a web browser :

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 9D FF 3D 2F 37 D7 22 AD 2E DB 87 35 AB 1A 4F CD B8 81 12 FC 31 B5 3E D6 BB CC 12 14 25 FD 4F 55
"Time": 12/02/1995 13:31:25
SessionID: D9 BF DE D8 2A 76 F7 E8 F1 3C A5 57 09 13 EA 20 A5 73 FF E9 74 90 BC 2C B9 64 B3 7C 0E 5C FC C3
Extensions: 
    grease (0x9a9a) empty
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    supported_groups    grease [0x2a2a], x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    SignedCertTimestamp (RFC6962)   empty
    0x4469      00 03 02 68 32
    key_share   00 29 2A 2A 00 01 00 00 1D 00 20 7F AD F4 4B C9 A7 9C 2E 28 80 A7 24 78 DD E3 4D 33 94 98 5C 46 16 6D 1F 86 53 62 2D F5 79 BC 5C
    psk_key_exchange_modes  01 01
    SessionTicket   empty
    renegotiation_info  00
    signature_algs  ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512
    extended_master_secret  empty
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    0x001b      02 00 02
    ALPN        h2, http/1.1
    supported_versions  grease [0x1a1a], Tls1.3, Tls1.2
    0xfe0d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
    server_name notasolutions.com
    grease (0xcaca) 00
Ciphers: 
    [0A0A]  Unrecognized cipher - See https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
    [1301]  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [1302]  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [1303]  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [CCA9]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [CCA8]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

With result :

```
This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
To view the encrypted sessions inside this tunnel, enable the Tools > Options > HTTPS > Decrypt HTTPS traffic option.

A SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
SessionID:  D9 BF DE D8 2A 76 F7 E8 F1 3C A5 57 09 13 EA 20 A5 73 FF E9 74 90 BC 2C B9 64 B3 7C 0E 5C FC C3
Random:     33 78 72 DA DC 11 F0 74 CF E0 C7 9F 79 0B 34 B9 3D 50 2D 4F 8F 03 5F 27 96 F4 18 8B 8E C7 EB D1
Cipher:     TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 [0x1302]
CompressionSuite:   NO_COMPRESSION [0x00]
Extensions:
        supported_versions  Tls1.3
        key_share   00 1D 00 20 9A EF 5C 31 9B 40 D8 B6 52 95 B4 21 CA A8 FB 5B 10 32 86 11 0B 20 C4 54 E4 4B A8 EB 92 CB 2C 52
```

Again, a normal suit of Cypher, with some of them being accepted by the server.

Here is the same trace when running the same powershell command line on my machine, and working fine :

```
Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 65 E0 E4 FC E8 64 59 2C 47 97 D8 47 1D 81 50 32 7D 38 3F 44 26 9A 2A 84 E2 48 0E 46 AE CC 9D AF
"Time": 14/06/2104 05:41:25
SessionID: 1E 33 00 00 0A F3 11 6E B7 E8 16 FC 31 6D 1D 08 6F 31 56 84 F0 AB 30 D4 F2 D0 BC 79 61 9A B4 9D
Extensions: 
    server_name notasolutions.com
    supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algs  rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
    SessionTicket   empty
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

When calling https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html from powershell, the results don't look incorrect. Except the order of the cipher suit, and some old protocols activated on this machine (if I reset them, the problem still exist), there is no major difference with my machine :

```
Protocols
TLS 1.3 Yes
TLS 1.2 Yes*
TLS 1.1 Yes*
TLS 1.0 Yes*
SSL 3   Yes*
SSL 2   No


Cipher Suites (in order of preference)
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)   Forward Secrecy   256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)   Forward Secrecy   128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)   Forward Secrecy  256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   Forward Secrecy  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   Forward Secrecy    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   Forward Secrecy    128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)  WEAK  256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)  WEAK  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)  WEAK    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)  WEAK    128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)  WEAK 256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)  WEAK 128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)  WEAK   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)  WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)  WEAK    256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)  WEAK    128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)  WEAK    256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)  WEAK    128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)  WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)  WEAK   128

Protocol Details
Server Name Indication (SNI)    Yes
Secure Renegotiation    Yes
TLS compression No
Session tickets Yes
OCSP stapling   No
Signature algorithms    SHA256/RSA, SHA384/RSA, SHA1/RSA, SHA256/ECDSA, SHA384/ECDSA, SHA1/ECDSA, SHA1/DSA, SHA512/RSA, SHA512/ECDSA
Named Groups    x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1
Next Protocol Negotiation   No
Application Layer Protocol Negotiation  No
SSL 2 handshake compatibility   No
```

If you have any idea, I would gladly share a teamviewer on one of the customer computer to help me troubleshoot this.
I have 200 customers in this case, where I workaround by changing the call to HTTP simple, which is of course not a good solution.

Thanks !

Comment: For reference, notasolutions.com use a let's encrypt certificate, but the same issue occurs when calling another website hosted on the same server, with a full fledge gandi certificate (example : demo.notaroom.fr), so I don't think the issue is related to a certificate trust issue.

Comment: Can we have the full exception message, including any `InnerException`? Also could you get a wireshark trace showing the Client and Server Hellos?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, sorry, there is no innerexception.
I'm working on the wireshark trace from client side. I'm not sure if I will be able to get the server side.
We are also upgrading the server reverse proxy this WE, hoping something will change.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, here is a link to the relevant wireshark :
https://ong.notaroom.fr/_layouts/15/NotaSolutions/Pages/NotaExchange/GetPublicFile.aspx?eid=4109f253-2925-4857-a451-9cd4286fc88d&fiid=39&key=8beccb934850442e824ad201035ddf078cc50d99fbffe4bf
The link will expire end of march.

Comment: For comparison, another trace with a tls success
https://ong.notaroom.fr/_layouts/15/NotaSolutions/Pages/NotaExchange/GetPublicFile.aspx?eid=4109f253-2925-4857-a451-9cd4286fc88d&fiid=41&key=4f0b8bf375c94a7b9fda775c616d73098b045f0a9c9df541

Comment: It look like the problem disappear when setting 
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
instead of SystemDefault. It also don't work if I set the value to Tls12|Tls13

Comment: Is that client machine fully up to date with all Windows updates?

Comment: Well. It's a win11 22H2 with no update visible in wupdate.
I have downgraded my server to only use TLS1.2 (so no 1.3) and this is an acceptable workaround for now.